# Simpel vs einfach

Tags: difference, synonym

> **einfach:**
>  a. leicht verständlich, durchführbar; ohne Mühe lösbar; unkompliziert, nicht schwierig 
>       b. leicht einsehbar; einleuchtend, eindeutig
>
> **simpel:** so einfach, dass es keines besonderen geistigen Aufwands bedarf, nichts weiter erfordert, leicht zu bewältigen ist; unkompliziert

Meine Theorie über den Unterschied: er besteht nur in der Intensität; simpel bedeutet mehr einfach als einfach. Ist diese Theorie korrekt?

Quelle: Duden

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl hat *simpel* eher leicht negative Konnotationen, *einfach* eher leicht positive. Ein Simpel ist ein einfältiger Mensch im negativen Sinne, aber wenn man jemand einfach nennt kann das auch positiv sein (im Vergleich zu komplizierten Menschen). Bei einer direkten Gegenüberstellung von *simpel* und *einfach* im Kontext einer Aufgabe würde ich *simpel* so verstehen, dass die Aufgabe eher kurz, knapp und verständlich formuliert ist oder keine besonderen Komplikationen enthält, und *einfach* eher so, dass sie leicht zu lösen ist.

Meine Suche nach Variationen von *simpel* und *einfach* in Googles n-gram-Viewer ([Beispiel](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=simpel%2Ceinfach&year_start=1700&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csimpel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ceinfach%3B%2Cc0)) hat ergeben, dass *einfach* immer das mit Abstand häufigere Wort war. In der 2. Hälfte des 18. Jahrhunderts war *simpel* anscheinend vorübergehend modern, wurde aber auch in der Zeit maximal halb so häufig wie *einfach* und verschwand danach wieder fast vollständig. Erst im 20. Jahrhundert kam es dann wieder hoch, vermutlich unter dem Einfluss des Englischen. Trotz des stetigen Anstiegs seiner Beliebtheit hat das Wort bisher weniger als 10% der Häufigkeit von *einfach* erreicht.

Comment: Könnte man das so sagen?
Tausend-mal am Stück in die Hände zu Klatschen ist simpel doch noch lange nicht einfach?

Answer (score 3):

"einfach" und "simpel" (lateinisch) ist von der Bedeutung her genau das Gleiche. Hier einen Unterschied sehen oder hineindeuten zu wollen, ist verkehrt.
Der Unterschied liegt in der Häufigkeit der Verwendung. Das normale Wort ist "einfach". "simpel" wird man in geschriebener Sprache nicht oft finden.
Und auch in gesprochener Sprache (abgesehen von Dialekten) wird es nicht oft verwendet.
Im Fränkischen sagt man gerne  "Du Simpel" (Du Dummkopf). Mir würden aber spontan keine typischen Wendungen mit "simpel" einfallen.

Answer (score 0):

Meine Theorie über den Unterschied:

Simpel ist aus dem Lateinischen abgeleitet und wird meines Erachtens eher von Leuten benutzt, die mal Latein in der Schule gelernt haben – wobei Hans Adler in einem Kommentar hinzugefügt hat, dass es in Dialekten anscheinend stärker verbreitet ist

Die Adjektive *einfach* und *simpel* würde ich als volle Synonyme wahrnehmen, also dass der Gebrauch quasi ausschließlich von persönlichen Vorlieben abhängt. (Zu *simpel* existiert allerdings kein Adverb, es kann also nicht Adjektive oder Verben beschreiben.)

Comment: @Downvoter: Bitte Kommentar, was falsch ist zum Verbessern.

Comment: Ich war nicht der Downvoter, aber: *Simpel* wird wie auch viele andere Wörter aus dem Französischen oder Lateinischen häufiger in bestimmten Dialekten als im Hochdeutsch verwendet. Weil das Wort jedem deutschen Muttersprachler geläufig ist und es auch im Englischen Standard ist, hat der Gebrauch mit Schullatein gar nichts zu tun. Und es ist simpel falsch, dass *simpel* ein volles Synonym für *einfach* ist - wie dieser Satz zeigt. Oder auch die Tatsache, dass eine simple (d.h. bloße) Rechenaufgabe nicht unbedingt einfach ist, und umgekehrt.

Comment: @HansAdler Dass man mit "eine simple Rechenaufgabe" zumindest je nach Kontext etwas anderes ausdrücken kann als mit "eine einfache Rechenaufgabe", ist eine feine Beobachtung. Leider erklärst Du das aber in Deiner eigenen Antwort nicht.

Comment: @HansAdler Ich bin wahrscheinlich zu sehr durch Sprachen beeinflusst, die Adverben und Adjektive sauber trennen – dass es kein Adverb *simpel* gibt war mir bekannt, und ist jetzt hoffentlich auch in der Antwort klarer. Über dialektale Verwendungsvorlieben war mir (schande über mich) nichts bekannt, das ist jetzt dazugeschrieben. Meine Beobachtung war tatsächlich, dass Gymnasiasten eher *simpel* sagen als Real-/Hauptschüler. Die feinen Unterschiede, die Matthias anspricht, sind mir nicht klar gewesen.

Comment: @Matthias: Was ist denn der Unterschied zw. einer simplen und einer einfachen Rechenaufgabe?